# PHP $_Session , JS not allowing member login after successful username and password inserted

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, session

so, this implementation worked with an md5 password check but after implementing a password hash check (for a safer password storage in my database) the member is not allowed to log in. The user after typing the correct email and password is only brought back to the index.php page. Any help would be appreciated. this is my session.php code:

```
<?php
     session_start(); 
    //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
    // do check

    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        // redirect them to your desired location
        header('Location: custom_404.html');
        exit;
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['alogin']) || (trim($_SESSION['alogin']) == '')) { ?>
    <!-- send to home page -->
    <script>
    window.location = "../index.php";
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    $session_id=$_SESSION['alogin'];
    $session_depart = $_SESSION['arole'];
    ?>
```

here is what should work within `index.php`:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include('includes/config.php');
    if(isset($_POST['signin']))
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $username=strtolower($username);
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $sql ="SELECT * FROM tblemployees where EmailId = '$username'";
        $query= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($count>0)
        {
            $passwordCheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)['Password'];
            if(!password_verify($password,$passwordCheck)){
                echo "<script>alert('Wrong password please try again.');</script>";
            }
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                if ($row['role'] == 'Admin') {
                    $_SESSION['alogin']=$row['emp_id'];
                    $_SESSION['arole']=$row['Department'];
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'admin/admin_dashboard.php'; </script>";
                }
                elseif ($row['role'] == 'Staff') {
                    $_SESSION['alogin']=$row['emp_id'];
                    $_SESSION['arole']=$row['Department'];
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'staff/index.php'; </script>";
                }
                else {
                    $_SESSION['alogin']=$row['emp_id'];
                    $_SESSION['arole']=$row['Department'];
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'heads/index.php'; </script>";
                }
            }
        } 
        else{
          
          echo "<script>alert('Wrong email or password please try again.');</script>";

        }

    }
    // $_SESSION['alogin']=$_POST['username'];
    //  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'changepassword.php'; </script>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include the actual code from your question [instead of an image of the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Use `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see what's actually saved in the session.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I changed it.

Comment: @Barmar Where should I put that snippet of code? How may I actually view the content of the session as well to see if its actually saving it. **UPDATED** - I have  found out the output is => array(0) { }. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login code is wrong. The loop

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
```

is never fetching anything, because you already read the row with

```
$passwordCheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)['Password'];
```

You should just fetch the row once, and use that for both the password and role checks.

You also should use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['signin']))
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $username=strtolower($username);
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $sql ="SELECT * FROM tblemployees where EmailId = ?";
    $stmt= mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $query = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    if($row)
    {
        $passwordCheck = $row['Password'];
        if(!password_verify($password,$passwordCheck)){
            echo "<script>alert('Wrong email or  password please try again.');</script>";
        } else {
            if ($row['role'] == 'Admin') {
                $_SESSION['alogin']=$row['emp_id'];
                $_SESSION['arole']=$row['Department'];
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'admin/admin_dashboard.php'; </script>";
            }
            elseif ($row['role'] == 'Staff') {
                $_SESSION['alogin']=$row['emp_id'];
                $_SESSION['arole']=$row['Department'];
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'staff/index.php'; </script>";
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['alogin']=$row['emp_id'];
                $_SESSION['arole']=$row['Department'];
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'heads/index.php'; </script>";
            }
        }
    } 
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Wrong email or password please try again.');</script>";
    }

}
// $_SESSION['alogin']=$_POST['username'];
//  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'changepassword.php'; </script>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help :)